# `find` only in certain subdirectories

Tags: linux, find

I have this directory structure

```
 $ tree test
test
├── test1
│   ├── test11
│   │   └── file.txt
│   ├── test12
│   │   └── file.txt
│   └── test13
│       └── file.txt
├── test2
│   └── file.txt
└── test3
    └── file.txt

6 directories, 5 files
```

and I want a find command that will return

```
$ find test -constrain_to_paths test/test{13} -name file.txt 
test/test3/file.txt
test/test1/test11/file.txt
test/test1/test12/file.txt
test/test1/test13/file.txt
```

So basically search for `file.txt` only in directories `test/test1` and `test/test3`. To get this going I tried this

```
$ find test \( -path './test3/*' -o -path './test2/*' \) -name file.txt
```

but it returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this answer could help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60850

For example: `find test/test1 test/test3 -name file.txt`

Comment: Welocome to SO. Thanks very much! For posterity the precise command I ended up using is `find test \( -path 'test/test3/*' -or -path 'test/test1/*' \) -and -name file.txt`